# Why periodic functions form a dense subset in $ C[a,b]$ with $L^2$ norm?

Tags: analysis

Let's consider the linear space $C[a,b]$ but with $L^2$ norm
$$
\|f\|=(\int_a^b |f(t)|^2dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

How to prove that the subspace
$$
V=\{f\in C[a,b]: f(a)=f(b)\}
$$
is dense in this normed space.

Thanks

Comment: Show that $V_0 = \{ f \in C[a,b] : f(a) = f(b) = 0\}$ is dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \in C[a,b].$ Set

$$f_n(x) = f(x)[(x-a)(b-x)]^{1/n}, n = 1,2,\dots .$$

Then $f_n \in V, n= 1,2,\dots$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a+\delta, b-\delta]$ for all small $\delta>0.$ This and the uniform boundedness of the $f_n$ will give $f_n\to f$ in the $L^2$-norm.